# What's the command for terminal to find the usb information?

Tags: command-line, usb

I know I can find the name of my flash drive by going `/media/user/nameOfFlashdrive` in the file manager. However, Is there a terminal command where I can enter the name of the flash drive and it will tell me where the drive is connected such as `/dev/sdb1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
lsblk | grep <flashdrive>
```

This will output in my situation, running

```
$ lsblk | grep Passport
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1,8T  0 part /media/jacob/My Passport1
└─sdc1   8:33   0 698,6G  0 part /media/jacob/My Passport
```

where you can see both the device and the mount point. As you can see, I have two usb drives named `My Passport`

#### Only get the device

```
$ lsblk | grep Passport | awk '{ print $1 }'
└─sdb1
└─sdc1
```

The same, but with a more precise output:

```
$ lsblk | grep Passport | awk -F'[─ ]' '{ print $2 }'
sdb1
sdc1
```

Or, as suggested by @kos (thanks!) even simpler, using `lsblk` with the `-l` option (which will leave out the `└─` in the output, before the devices):

```
$ lsblk -l | grep Passport | awk '{ print $1 }'
sdb1
sdc1
```

Or (also as suggested by @kos), you could do without the `grep` command, only using `lsblk` and `awk`:

```
$ lsblk -l | awk '/Passport/{ print $1 }'
sdb1
sdc1
```

#### Explanation

- `lsblk` will list all your mounted devices
- `grep <flashdrive>` will only list the line(s), matching with your device name, looking like:

  ```
  └─sdc1   8:33   0 698,6G  0 part /media/jacob/My Passport
  ```
- `awk -F'[─ ]' '{ print $2 }'` will split the line by two delimiters:

  ```
  ─
  ```

  (which is the second character from └─)

  and a space.

Subsequently, we can easily get the section we need.

Comment: No 1 is named "My Passport1" >:-D

Comment: @Rinzwind sharp :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm is it possible to just obtain the name "sdb1"

Comment: @user2669764 like this? (see edit)

Comment: @kos I had the feeling someone could improve me here, in this foreign country, outside `python` thanks! I will edit it into the answer :). I am not sure about `gawk`, not being on Ubuntu by default. This one (my computer) is pretty much non- standard, but my wife's computer has a totally basic installation, including `gawk`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm prior to 15.04, I think, Ubuntu was coming by default with mawk. Some packages like byobu list gawk as dependency, thus your wife's computer may have originally had mawk but once you installed some software, you got gawk

Comment: @kos Are you sure? my wife's computer is 14.04, pretty (totally) basic.

Comment: Also `lsblk` has `-r` flag, which is raw mode, used specifically when output is needed to be processed by tools like AWK

Comment: @Serg thanks! In this case, it won't make much difference. In older scripts of mine however, it does save some code! Silly that I never looked into `man lsblk` to look for specific output format...

Comment: I booted the live images for 14.04.4 and 15.10 just to be completely sure... `readlink -f $(which awk)` outputs `/usr/bin/mawk` in in both (don't have a 15.04 image handy, but IIRC it should be the same). Many people have GAWK installed though, probably some common packages install it. I always remember this because I remember the first failed attempts with stock `awk` using GNU syntax... I think the rationale is that MAWK has been proven 8-9 times faster than GAWK at times (and probably the typical newcomer Linux / Ubuntu user won't even need to use `awk` directly, in general).

Comment: @kos isn't the live image a stripped version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Doesn't it load the same squashfs filesystem that is copied during the installation? However what happens if you run this: `comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)`? If you have `gawk` in the results it means it has been installed manually *after* Ubuntu's installation (the command shows all the installed manually packages excluding those listed in `/var/log/installer/initial-status.gz`)

Comment: @kos had to increase the cache to get all the lines :), but no, no `gawk`.

Comment: Weird. Obviously I do trust you, but I'm also pretty sure GAWK syntax didn't work in 14.04 by default. I'm installing it in a VM now just to see what's going on, because I'm curious. Maybe it's installed with Ubuntu but `awk` is still symlinked to `/usr/bin/mawk` by default?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36210/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-kos).

Answer (score 4):

There's several commands for that actually. One can always filter out the output, using text processing tools, generally their output is small enough to read in one screenfull.

#### `blkid`

This neat command by itself  , as the name suggests, shows info about block devices. With `-L` you can search for specific device with a label (name).

```
$ blkid -L DTSE9                                               
/dev/sdb1
```

#### `df`

This neat command is part of `coreutils` package, shows the block size and usage of the "device files".  It shows only informations about those devices that are mounted ( in other words, linked to a folder somewhere ). For instance,

```
/dev/sdb5      115247656 84753976  24616332  78% /media/WINDOWS
```

Tells me that my windows partition on the second hard drive is linked to `/media/WINDOWS` partition.

#### `udisksctl`

```
$ udisksctl status                                             
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Radeon R7                 1.01      A22MD061520000172    sda     
TSSTcorp CDDVDW SU-208GB  TF01      S16T6YEFB00NKH       sr0
```

Very convenient command that lists models and device file to which a disk is linked. In the example above my Radeon R7 SSD is linked to `/dev/sda` device.

If we go into more details, `udisksctl info -b /dev/sda` will list lots of additional info , including size and symlinks.

If we wanna go wild, `udisksctl dump` will produce verbose output on all the disks.

#### `parted` and `fdisk`

Both commands are disks utilities, used for partitioning, resizing, and many more other fun things. Both however, require use of `sudo`. Both output great verbose information

#### `find`

This is a more "hands on" approach. All the devices have a special device file under Linux ( remember Unix philosophy that says everything is a file ? It applies here the best ).  Knowing that there are files `/dev/disk/by-label` we could search that directory, or we could just search `/dev/disk` in general.  Definitely a tool that more advanced users can appreciate

```
$ find -L /dev/disk/by-label/ -name "DTSE9" -exec readlink -e {} \;               
/dev/sdb1
```

#### `lsblk`

Already covered by Jacob.

#### `mount`

```
$ mount | grep "DTSE9"                                                            
/dev/sdb1 on /media/xieerqi/DTSE9 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Lists all mounted filesystems. Can be filtered with `grep` to look for specific filesystem. It's analogous to doing `grep 'DISKNAME OR UUID' /proc/mounts`

#### `lshw`

This command provides info about all the hardware on the system. In particular, you can view info about disks using `lshw -c disk` for whole device, or `lshw -c volume` for partitions,
and you should see output with lines something like this:

```
logical name: /dev/sdc1
   logical name: /media/xieerqi/BA02-AF80
```

Answer (score 1):

...appending to the comprehensive answers above:

#### `lsusb`

`lsusb` is  a  utility for displaying information about USB buses in the
       system and the devices connected to them.

See [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/lsusb.8.html). !

Comment: This is a good answer for the title of this question, but not really the question itself. That's why I upvoted this and why the other answers probably didn't include it.